# d3.scale.category20() is returning same color

Tags: d3.js

As documentation says **d3.scale.category20()** [Constructs a new ordinal scale with a range of twenty categorical colors:](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Ordinal-Scales#category20). But I am getting the same color. What Am I doing Wrong?

```js
var color = '';
for (i = 1; i < 21; i++) {
   var test = d3.scale.category20();
   color += test(i);
}
document.write(color);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating the color scale every time in the for loop.

Move this outside the for loop     `var colorscale = d3.scale.category20();`

```js
var color = '';
var colorscale = d3.scale.category20();
for (i = 1; i < 21; i++) {

   color = colorscale(i);
   document.write("<br>");
   document.write(color);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```